# How to use external PHP file in laravel blade.php file?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to include external PHP file (`pdate.php`) in Laravel and use it in `blade.php` file. How can I do it?

The PHP file imported in `app\date\pdate.php`  folder and by using `app_path()` function in controller I try to send it in `blade.php` but there is error.

```
public function index(){
  include_once(app_path() . '/date/pdate.php');
  return view('/cashWithdraw/create');
}
```

When I use one variable of that file in `blade.php` I will get this error.

> Undefined variable: today (View: E:\laravelProject\deal\resources\views\cashWithdraw\create.blade.php)

Comment: what does your "app\date\pdate.php" file do? Is there any variable in it? Is it a partial or can the file add features to your view?

Answer (score 0):

In `composer.json` file you just add needed files in **“autoload”** section – in a new entry called `files`:

```
 "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/date/pdate.php"
    ]
},
```

after that run this command `composer dump-autoload` now you can use any function in this file globally

Comment: every thing is done but still there is error.@Joseph

Comment: after i use one variable from that file {{$today}} in cashWithdraw.blade.php i will get this error:Undefined variable: today (View: E:\laravelProject\deal\resources\views\cashWithdraw\create.blade.php)

Comment: aha you use it in your view you need to pass this variable from your controller method that called this blade using ``compact `` like this ``view('your view', compact('today'))``

Comment: did you try **Tim Lewis** answer it may help you

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using the `blade` `@include()` helper. If you save your file as a `pdate.blade.php` file, for example in `resources/views/date`, then you can include it as follows:

Inside of `cashWithdraw/create.blade.php`:

```
@include("date/pdate")
```

The only catch is that the variables available in `pdate.blade.php` need to be defined, but that can be done in a number of ways:

Directly in `pdate.blade.php`:

```
@php $today = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); @endphp
```

In the controller that returns `create.blade.php`:

```
public function index(){
  $today = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
  return view('cashWithdraw.create')->with(["today" => $today]);
}
```

In the `@includes` within `create.blade.php`:

```
@include("date/pdate", ["today" => \Carbon\Carbon::now()])
```

Comment: I created pdate.blade.php and included in create.blade.php,but when I am trying to echo (vaule="@php $today; @endphp") it shows nothing.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use `echo` in a `.blade.php` file; there's syntax for that, like `<input value="{{ $today }}"/>`, etc. As other answers have said, you should include the contents of `pdate.blade.php` in your question (at least the relevant snippet including the definition and usage of `$today`) so it's easier for us to answer. Actually, at second glance, `@php $today; @endphp` doesn't actually output anything; that's probably part of your issue too. Using the proper syntax, `{{ $today }}` should work for you. `@php @endphp` is for assigning, `{{ }}` is for `echo`ing.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing any variables into your view.  You will need to pass any variables generated by pdate into the view.

```
public function index(){
    include_once(app_path() . '/date/pdate.php');

    return view('/cashWithdraw/create', [
        'today' => $today
    ]);
}
```

The only variables that will be available in your blade are the ones you pass in there.

Comment: there is error ,how laravel knows that $today variable is inside pdate.php Undefined variable: today (View: E:\laravelProject\deal\resources\views\cashWithdraw\create.blade.php)

Comment: I was assuming that pdate.php created that variable.  Without seeing what's inside pdate, I don't know what it's doing.  Does it contain functions?  Classes?  Procedural code?

Comment: I guess I need to know where `$today` is coming from.

Comment: yes its create the $today variable, when i include it in PHP file and  echo $toady its show me the date, but in laravel its show that error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of pdate.php?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is a class, you can inject it into a view by using service injection as follows:

```
@inject('pdata', 'app\date\pdate')
```

then invoke any method. Assuming your class has one like getMyDate:

```
<div class="anything">
   {{ $pdata->getMyDate() }}
</div>
```